# Dual Boot Lost this morning

Tags: boot

I shut down computer after completing a session.
When I booted for the next session, the startup menu no longer provided the option to boot with Windows.
FileManager/Nautilus still shows existence of Windows partition and all of its files, but I don't have boot option (gParted still says that partition is flagged as bootable)

How do I get the lost boot option back?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the procedure on this eHow article to reinstall your grub bootloader.
http://www.ehow.com/how_8680603_reinstall-grub-2.html

"Click the "System" option, then select "Administration" and "Boot Repair." This will launch the "Boot Repair" graphical interface."

You can also install "Boot-Repair," if you do not have it. It is nice and GUI, and it does a good job.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Checkt this link out.